# Can't call a 'write' function using ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I try to interact with a contract on my local hardhat network.

Here's how i declare a contract instance:

```js
const account0 = "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80";
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/", 31337);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account0, provider);
const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
```

I then use `eth_requestAccounts` method:

```js
userAccount = (await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }))[0];
```

But when i do this:

```js
(elections.connect(userAccount)).vote(`${document.getElementById("voteFor").value}`, 1)
// where 'vote' is a 'write' function that takes 2 parameters
```

I get this error: `Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.7.0)`.

Brief explanation: I want to create a simple website using plain html/js where people could vote. PS: I'm just learning.

Thanks all the kind people in advance!

Comment: You mentioned you're using building this with plain HTML and Javascript. ***Is your script deferred so that it runs when all external scripts are already loaded?*** You should make sure `userAccount` is a non-empty value.

Comment: Also, you're supposed to get the signer like this when testing with `Hardhat`:



`
// Get the signers; accounts 0 through 2
let signer0 = provider.getSigner(0);
let signer1 = provider.getSigner(1);
let signer2 = provider.getSigner(2);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the smart contract on the front-end, calling this line should be fine:

```js
userAccount = (await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }))[0];
```

However, in `Hardhat`, you're supposed to retrieve the signers like this:

```js
// Get the signers; accounts 0 through 2
let signer0 = provider.getSigner(0);
let signer1 = provider.getSigner(1);
let signer2 = provider.getSigner(2);
```

Because there's no `window` object in NodeJS.

---

***(Answer updated based on the new commend)***

This code below actually returns an `array[string]`:

```js
await window.ethereum.request({
  "method": "eth_requestAccounts",
  "params": []
});
```

If you want to call a write method, you should pass a signer (**not just a string**) here:

```js
(elections.connect(userAccount)).vote(`${document.getElementById("voteFor").value}`, 1)
```

This approach above is incorrect and is the culprit of the `Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.7.0)` error.

So to solve that problem you should connect your `elections` contract to a **real signer** like this:

```js
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account0, provider);
const elections = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);

await ((elections.connect(signer)).vote(...pass your agruments here));
```

In a real-world application, you'd retrieve the signer the following way (*using ethers.js to interact with Metamask*):

```js
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
// It will prompt user for account connections if it isnt connected
const signer = await provider.getSigner(); // pass it to the .connect(...) function later

console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());
```

Comment: The thing is  that it's a not NodeJS. As i already said, i try to build a website. I made a smart contract and i deploy it using 'hardhat-deploy' plug-in (that contract gets deployed automatically when i spin up a node using hardhat). I imported a couple of hardhat accounts to my Metamask to try to tinker with that too. But the thing is that I don't know how to make my website to be able to perform 'write' functions to that contract on my local node on a user's behalf. Anyways, thank you for your answer

Comment: Aah, OK, see the updated solution that I suggest should work in your case. I updated my answer above. ⬆️

Comment: Thank you, kind guy, it indeed helped!